# jquery ui autocomplete get value of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How can i get the value of the selected option in the menu that is created by jquery ui autocomplete into a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var value = $("#the_input_ID").val();
```

if you want to be notified when a value is selected you can use something along the lines like this:

```
var selected_value;
$( "#your_input_id" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) {
        selected_value = $(ui).val();
   }
});
```

Comment: i want to get the value without getting it by the field in that jquery ui it writes.

Comment: @Julian can you be more explicite. Do you want to be notified when the user select something or something completely different?

Comment: @Julian i've updated my question, is this what you want. this way the selected function is called when the user selects something and that value is saved in the `selected_value`

Comment: ok its so: i want to get the value that the user selects because the answer from the server that uses autocomplete have a lot of options and i want have the option that the user choses. I dont want to use the field because if i first use the value that is written in the field and i then change the value that is written in the field the user of the website see this(that the value changes). Because that i  want to find another straighter way to get the value and than i dont want to write the value with jquery ui in the field. Sorry for my bad english :S

Answer (score -1):

The input that you use to create the autocomplete stores the value.

```
$("#myField").val();
```

or you get it if you submit your code with that ID.

Comment: my problem is that i want to get the value of the selected option of the user without using the field in which is entered the value. I want to do some thinks with the selected value and then write it into 3 different fields.